# Blackjack style python (computer) game looping incorrectly

Tags: python, if-statement, blackjack

The major problem I'm having is what occurs when I choose `stay` on `hand_one`, and then `hit` on `hand_two`.

Instead of asking me to `hit or stay` on `hand_two` again, it brings me back to `hit or stay` on `hand_one`, when I already chose stay on hand_one, **so hand_one should have no more options**. This causes issues with multiple print statements occurring and incorrect game play.

**What is wrong with my code that it is like causing it to loop back to `hand_one`.**
The full code is here: http://labs.codecademy.com/Bjaf/2#:workspace

Here is the part likely causing the issue.

```
def hit_or_stay(person):
    hit_or_stay = raw_input("Do you want to hit or stay? You can type h or s.")
    if hit_or_stay == 'h' or hit_or_stay == 'hit':
        deal_one_card(person)
        value_of_current_cards(person)
        number_value_of_hand()
    elif hit_or_stay == 's'or hit_or_stay == 'stay':
        print "You stayed"
        return
    else:
        hit_or_stay(person)

def number_value_of_hand():
    if number_of_hands > 0:
        value_of_hand_one = value_of_current_cards(hand_one)
        if value_of_hand_one < 18:
            print "\n" "You have %i" % (value_of_hand_one)
            hit_or_stay(hand_one)
        elif value_of_hand_one > 18:
            print "You Lose"
            return
        elif value_of_hand_one == 18:
            print "You hit HOT 18!!!"
            return
        if number_of_hands > 1:
            value_of_hand_two = value_of_current_cards(hand_two)
            if value_of_hand_two < 18:
                print "\n" "Your second hand has %i" % (value_of_hand_two)
                hit_or_stay(hand_two)
            elif value_of_hand_two > 18:
                print "You Lose"
                return
            elif value_of_hand_two == 18:
                print "You hit HOT 18!!!"
                return

number_value_of_hand()
```

Can anyone see why it loops back to give hand_one another option? And possibly how I can fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: hit_or_stay calls number_value_of_hand, which puts the line of execution back at the start of number_value_of_hand.

Comment: This seems like a classic example of code that would be much easier to implement in a class

Comment: In the hit_or_call function. add a parameter for hand1\hand2. Pass this back to number_value_of_hand and use it to check which hand to continue on.

Comment: Where are you defining the number of hands? If you have a method defining the number of hands and what their initial values are then it would be best to call these two methods inside that one, passing the updated values back into it. This would treat the values of each hand as pseudo-global and be a lot easier to loop over. Also, please include the deal_one_card() and value_of_current_cards() methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem occurs on  this step:

```
hit_or_stay(hand_two)
```

When you hit on hand_two, your code does this:

```
deal_one_card(person)
value_of_current_cards(person)
number_value_of_hand()
```

The problem is right there, because `number_value_of_hand()` brings you back to the beginning of that function, and goes through the hand_one options again.

You will probably have to rewrite your `number_value_of_hand()` function to include an argument that tells it where to begin (hand_one, hand_two, etc.)

I would probably make a `list` of hands, and iterate through the list.  Then, you could call `number_of_hands(hands[i])` to being at the `i`th hand.